# YouTube v3 API multiple search queries in search channel videos

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-api

I am sending requests to the YouTube v3 API at the following endpoint:

```js
const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${process.env.YOUTUBE_API_KEY}&part=snippet&q=foo`;
```

I am going to change this to use `channelId` to specify a channel as `foo` is the channel name. I want to also use the `search:list` functionality to search for videos within a specific channel that have titles containing keywords that as I understand can be passed via the `q` parameter.

Is there a way to provide multiple values for `q` as I need to search video titles on multiple criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters)

> q string: The `q` parameter specifies the query term to search for.

> Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (`-`) and OR (`|`) operators to exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing. Similarly, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the q parameter value to `boating|sailing -fishing`. Note that the pipe character must be URL-escaped when it is sent in your API request. The URL-escaped value for the pipe character is `%7C`.

You can also try out the API on that [page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix=true) itself, see the Try it! button on the right navbar.

There you can experiment with all the parameters and it will give out code in js, java, PHP, python directly.

Comment: But can you retrieve urls for multiple videos at the same time? Much like how wikipedia API allows you to retrieve the pageID(or url) of upto 50 pages, in one request